# Event immediatelly as another item is selected in DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I initialize cells from a list like this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
List<string> itemNames = new List<string>(new string[]
{
    "ITEM 1",
    "ITEM 2",
    "ITEM 3",
    "Add new item..."
});
row.CreateCells(myDataGridView);
row.Cells[0].Value = "";
if(row.Cells[1] is DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell2)
{
    cell2.DataSource = itemNames;
}
```

In the real program, the list is loaded from somewhere and the `"Add new item..."` entry is added at the end. What I want is to show a form when `"Add new item..."` is selected in the combobox.

```
    protected void checkIfNewItemSelected(DataGridViewComboBoxCell combocell)
    {
        if (combocell.Value + "" == ADD_CONFIG_TEXT)
        {
            // do something to add new item (show a form)
        }
    }
```

However I cannot find any suitable event that would trigger immediatelly after user selects the value. For example I tried `CellEndEdit` and [`CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on the datagrid. Both of these events trigger only after the combobox loses focus. Specifically the [latter is recommended by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

```
    private void dataGridViewConfigs_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridViewConfigs.CurrentCell;
        // handle trigger for new PRJ config request
        if (cell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell combocell)
        {
            checkIfNewItemSelected(combocell);
        }
    }
```

So if you select the `"Add new item..."`, this is what you end up seeing:

[image]

Only after you click somewhere else, the events that I tried are triggered. I need to take action IMMEDIATELY after user clicks on this particular entry.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook up to the events directly on the editing control, for example...

```
private const string NEW_ITEM_TEXT = "Add new item..";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboCol.Items.AddRange("A", "B", NEW_ITEM_TEXT);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboCol);
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;            
}

private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox == null) return;
    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl editor = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (editor.SelectedItem.ToString() != NEW_ITEM_TEXT) return;
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to very that the combobox is really the one I want to check? Can I find for which column and row is the control showing?

Comment: Yes, in EditingControlShowing event handler you can check `dataGridView1.CurrentCell` and from there get the row/column.